# HTML table displaying values < and > as text &lt; &gt;

Tags: html, mysql, json, response

I have a this weird thing. 
I have link defined in mysql view column.

```
CONCAT(
  '<a href=\'infoloan/',
  sms.loan_id,
  '\'>#</a>') AS `linkToLoan`
```

And it all looks very fine.
[image]

But then in the web it is displayed as text instead of my link.
[image]

This is because < is parsed as `&lt;` and > as `&gt;` in json response.
Lets say:

```
"&lt;a href=&#39;infoloan/22380&#39;&gt;#&lt;/a&gt;"
```

[image]

How to make web page to display it properly.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to render the table?

Comment: Why are you building HTML with SQL statements?

Comment: As a last resort you can always use `string.replace(/&lt;/ig,"<").replace(/&gt;/ig,">");`, but you may want to find out where exactly this conversion is happening. It might be an automated security feature from Chrome or MySQL or JSON against injection, but it might also be in one of the scripts you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the data prior to the JSON parser then I would decode it with `html_entity_decode()`